# Open PDF file in browser rather than downloading pdf file

Tags: c#, html, pdf, download

I want to allow user to open or save PDF file  rather than PDF file downloads it automatically.

Let us say i have a simple anchor tag

`<a href="pdf/pdf-file1.pdf" > View PDF </a>`

I tried to use `download` as well as `type="application/pdf"` in the anchor it self but it does not work.

I can force PDF file to open using C# code behind file, but I want to avoid that is there a simple HTML based way of doing it, not even in HTML 5

Comment: Unless you have some very, very, very good reasons, one should leave the way PDFs are handled and displayed to the user. If it is important to show the document in the browser, you can force this by rendering it server-side.

Comment: I don't mind default behavior but it is a client request. Just wanted to know if it can be done using HTML only. I can do it from code behind using  HTTP Handler also.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting this pdf yourself? If so, try adding `target="_blank"` to the anchor tag:

```
<a href="pdf/pdf-file1.pdf" target="_blank"> View PDF </a>
```

Otherwise, try an iframe:

```
<iframe src="pdf/pdf-file1.pdf" 
style="width:600px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Also, if you're sending this file from your own backend set the Content-Disposition to inline in your response:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="pdf-file1.pdf"
```

Comment: Yes this pdf file is on same server I had tried `target="_blank"` earlier it didnt work either

Comment: for last part of your solution i have to either add it in C# code or made changes to IIS setting which i dont want to. I want something simple to make it work if possible directly from the anchor tag

Comment: It's not possible to do with 100% reliability from the anchor tag because the browser determines how downloaded files will display. For best results, you should really change the `content-disposition` server-side.